# sum of value occurrence grouped by another column pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to count the occurrence of each value in column `name` and group by column `industry`. The goal is to get the sum of each name per industry.
My data looks like this:

```
industry            name
Home             Mike
Home             Mike,Angela,Elliot
Fashion          Angela,Elliot
Fashion          Angela,Elliot
```

The desired output is:

```
Home Mike:2 Angela:1 Elliot:1
Fashion Angela:2 Elliot:2
```

Comment: `df['name'] = df['name'].str.split(','); df.explode('name').groupby(['industry', 'name'], as_index=False).count()`

Comment: @Marat why not post it as answer ?

Comment: @sushanth it's too trivial (both the question and the answer). Also, I didn't want to fully debug it, now it is more of a direction to look at

Comment: @Marat I agree with you , but overall a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving this out of comments, debugged and proved working:

```
# count() in the next line won't work without an extra column
df['name_list'] = df['name'].str.split(',')
df.explode('name_list').groupby(['industry', 'name_list']).count()
```

Result:

```
                    name
industry name_list      
Fashion  Angela        2
         Elliot        2
Home     Angela        1
         Elliot        1
         Mike          2
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `collections.Counter` to return a series of dictionaries as follows:

```
from collections import Counter
s = df.name.str.split(',').groupby(df.industry).sum().agg(Counter)

Out[506]:
industry
Fashion               {'Angela': 2, 'Elliot': 2}
Home       {'Mike': 2, 'Angela': 1, 'Elliot': 1}
Name: name, dtype: object
```

**Note**: Each cell is a `Counter` object. `Counter` is a subclass of dictionary, so you can apply dictionary operations on it as an dictionary.